# Oracle SQL display a different column depending on the date

Tags: oracle

I have a table that has 33 columns

```
Employee     Month    Day1    Day2 ...... etc. etc.
```

The day column represents the day of the month.

Is it possible to just display the Employee column and the Day of the month depending on today's date?

i.e.

12th May

Employee    Day12

no idea where to start if it's possible. any help would be great

Comment: post queries you have tried

Comment: not sure where to start with it sorry, not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: @LeeTyler Post the create and insert statements for the table. We don't know how your table looks like and what is the data. You must provide the sample data.

Comment: Well, that looks like a weird table design. So there is a record per employee and month. And Day1, Day2, etc. hold values for that day. Today, on May 12, the months June till December mean 2014; and January till May 11 mean the past days of 2015. Right? And you want to pick the May record for each employee and show the value for Day12

Comment: what actually going to store in day1 , day2 column ? i guess you can think of your table design as  3 column  Employee , Date , value. This will help to get good implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a record (here: month) with the WHERE clause. You get a certain column (here: day) with DECODE or CASE.

```
select 
  employee, 
  decode( extract(day from sysdate), 1, day1, 2, day2, 3, day3, ... ) as day
from mytable t
where t.month = extract(month from sysdate)
group by employee
order by employee;
```

Comment: The problem is that OP wants to select the column dynamically. The only ay is (ab)using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in PL/SQL.

Comment: This is dynamic. Quote: "depending on today's date". So today you get May 12, tomorrow you'll get May 13.

Comment: Works! thanks so much!! :) the where extract bit didn't work but i can work around that :)